# Cygwin .bashrc PATH gets duplicate entries

Tags: bash, path, cygwin

I've got the following variable set in my cygwin $HOME/.bashrc

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/sbin:"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin":$PATH
```

Problem is that when I login and the .bashrc gets executed, I get starting duplicates as follows:

```
Dragos@dragos ~
$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/bin
/usr/sbin
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
/cygdrive/c/curl
/
/cygdrive/c/gnupg
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/cvsnt
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/GNU/WinCvs 2.0
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/Notepad++
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/PuTTY
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/WinSCP
/cygdrive/c/Python26
/cygdrive/c/Python26/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/bin
/cygdrive/c/Python26/Scripts
/usr/bin
/usr/lib/lapack
```

Does anyone know what causes this?

Here's my `.bashrc`

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc    
# base-files version 3.7-1

# To pick up the latest recommended .bashrc content,
# look in /etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bashrc

# Modifying /etc/skel/.bashrc directly will prevent
# setup from updating it.

# The copy in your home directory (~/.bashrc) is yours, please
# feel free to customise it to create a shell
# environment to your liking.  If you feel a change
# would be benificial to all, please feel free to send
# a patch to the cygwin mailing list.

# User dependent .bashrc file

# Shell Options
# #############

# See man bash for more options...

# Don't wait for job termination notification
# set -o notify

# Don't use ^D to exit
# set -o ignoreeof

# Use case-insensitive filename globbing
# shopt -s nocaseglob

# Make bash append rather than overwrite the history on disk
# shopt -s histappend

# When changing directory small typos can be ignored by bash
# for example, cd /vr/lgo/apaache would find /var/log/apache
# shopt -s cdspell


# Completion options
# ##################

# These completion tuning parameters change the default behavior of bash_completion:

# Define to access remotely checked-out files over passwordless ssh for CVS
# COMP_CVS_REMOTE=1

# Define to avoid stripping description in --option=description of './configure --help'
# COMP_CONFIGURE_HINTS=1

# Define to avoid flattening internal contents of tar files
# COMP_TAR_INTERNAL_PATHS=1

# If this shell is interactive, turn on programmable completion enhancements.
# Any completions you add in ~/.bash_completion are sourced last.
# case $- in
#   *i*) [[ -f /etc/bash_completion ]] && . /etc/bash_completion ;;
# esac


# History Options
# ###############

# Don't put duplicate lines in the history.
# export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"

# Ignore some controlling instructions
# export HISTIGNORE="[   ]*:&:bg:fg:exit"

# Whenever displaying the prompt, write the previous line to disk
# export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"


# Aliases
# #######

# Some example alias instructions
# If these are enabled they will be used instead of any instructions
# they may mask.  For example, alias rm='rm -i' will mask the rm
# application.  To override the alias instruction use a \ before, ie
# \rm will call the real rm not the alias.

# Interactive operation...
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'

# Default to human readable figures
# alias df='df -h'
# alias du='du -h'

# Misc :)
# alias less='less -r'                          # raw control characters
# alias whence='type -a'                        # where, of a sort
# alias grep='grep --color'                     # show differences in colour

# Some shortcuts for different directory listings
alias ls='ls -hF --color=tty'                 # classify files in colour
# alias dir='ls --color=auto --format=vertical'
# alias vdir='ls --color=auto --format=long'
# alias ll='ls -l'                              # long list
# alias la='ls -A'                              # all but . and ..
# alias l='ls -CF'                              #

# Functions
# #########

# Some example functions
# function settitle() { echo -ne "\e]2;$@\a\e]1;$@\a"; }

# Notepad++ function
# Pass in a UNIX path
# Starts notepad++ given a UNIX path argument
function notepadpp() { 
  local notepadUnixPath="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
  #local notepadArgPath=$(eval $(echo cygpath -w -a "$*"))
  local notepadArgPath=`cygpath -w -a "$*"`
  "$notepadUnixPath" -multiInst "$notepadArgPath" &
}

alias notepad++=notepadpp

# Explorer function
# Pass in a UNIX path
# Starts explorer given a UNIX path argument
function explorer() { 
  local explorerArgPath=`cygpath -w -a "$*"`
  cmd /C start "" "$explorerArgPath" &
}

alias vi=vim

# Change filename starting with prefix string to another prefix string
alias mvprefix='$HOME/mvprefix.sh'

# Change filename ending with suffix string to another suffix string
alias mvsuffix='$HOME/mvsuffix.sh'

# Change filename ending with suffix string to a string prefixed with todays date
alias todaysuffix='$HOME/todaysuffix.sh'

# Generate secure passwords by default 
alias pwgen='pwgen -y -c -s -n'

export INPUTRC=$HOME/.inputrc
export EDITOR=vim
export PATH=/bin:/usr/sbin:"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin":$PATH

# Overwrite DOS env variable APPDATA with our own for installing perl CPANPLUS
export APPDATA=$HOME
```

Here's my `.bash_profile`

```
$ cat .bash_profile
# base-files version 3.7-1

# To pick up the latest recommended .bash_profile content,
# look in /etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bash_profile

# Modifying /etc/skel/.bash_profile directly will prevent
# setup from updating it.

# The copy in your home directory (~/.bash_profile) is yours, please
# feel free to customise it to create a shell
# environment to your liking.  If you feel a change
# would be benifitial to all, please feel free to send
# a patch to the cygwin mailing list.

# ~/.bash_profile: executed by bash for login shells.

# source the system wide bashrc if it exists
if [ -e /etc/bash.bashrc ] ; then
  source /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -e "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi

# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}
# fi

# Set MANPATH so it includes users' private man if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/man" ]; then
#   MANPATH=${HOME}/man:${MANPATH}
# fi

# Set INFOPATH so it includes users' private info if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/info" ]; then
#   INFOPATH=${HOME}/info:${INFOPATH}
# fi
```

Here's my `/etc/bash.bashrc`

```
$ cat /etc/bash.bashrc
# To the extent possible under law, the author(s) have dedicated all
# copyright and related and neighboring rights to this software to the
# public domain worldwide. This software is distributed without any warranty.
# You should have received a copy of the CC0 Public Domain Dedication along
# with this software.
# If not, see <http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>.

# base-files version 4.1-1

# /etc/bash.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for interactive shells.

# The latest version as installed by the Cygwin Setup program can
# always be found at /etc/defaults/etc/bash.bashrc

# Modifying /etc/bash.bashrc directly will prevent
# setup from updating it.

# System-wide bashrc file

# Check that we haven't already been sourced.
([[ -z ${CYG_SYS_BASHRC} ]] && CYG_SYS_BASHRC="1") || return

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return

# Set a default prompt of: user@host and current_directory
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '

# Uncomment to use the terminal colours set in DIR_COLORS
# eval "$(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)"
```

I don't modify $PATH in my $HOME/.bashrc anywhere other than the set `PATH=` command above.

If I prepend only one path to $PATH, that would get duplicated as well:

```
PATH="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin":$PATH
```

Results in:

```
Dragos@dragos ~
$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
/cygdrive/c/curl
/
/cygdrive/c/gnupg
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/cvsnt
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/GNU/WinCvs 2.0
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/Notepad++
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/PuTTY
/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/WinSCP
/cygdrive/c/Python26
/cygdrive/c/Python26/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/bin
/cygdrive/c/Python26/Scripts
/usr/bin
/usr/lib/lapack
```

So... Why the duplicates?

Addendum:

I found that I'm executing bash twice in my `C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`
The reason is that I have a context menu command to "Open Bash Here" that passes 
a starting path to `C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`

Here's my `C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`

```
@echo off

C:

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin

REM SHELL needed for any screen instances started from bash
set SHELL=/bin/bash
set HOME=C:\cygwin\home\Dragos
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\cygwin\home\Dragos

REM 

if not [%1]==[] (
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygpath %1 > tmpFile
  set /p startingpath= < tmpFile
  del tmpFile
)

if "%startingpath%"=="" start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --icon /Cygwin-Terminal.ico --size 140,50 --exec /bin/bash --login -c "exec /bin/bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc"
if not "%startingpath%"=="" start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --icon /Cygwin-Terminal.ico --size 140,50 --exec /bin/bash --login -c "cd '%startingpath%'; exec /bin/bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc"
exit
```

Addendum:

Figured out that I need to pass `--noprofile --norc` to bash when calling bash.
Here's the updated `C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`

```
@echo off

C:

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin

REM SHELL needed for any screen instances started from bash
set SHELL=/bin/bash
set HOME=C:\cygwin\home\Dragos
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\cygwin\home\Dragos

REM 

if not [%1]==[] (
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygpath %1 > tmpFile
  set /p startingpath= < tmpFile
  del tmpFile
)

if "%startingpath%"=="" start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --icon /Cygwin-Terminal.ico --size 140,50 --exec /bin/bash --login
if not "%startingpath%"=="" start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --icon /Cygwin-Terminal.ico --size 140,50 --exec /bin/bash --noprofile --norc --login -c "cd '%startingpath%'; exec /bin/bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc"

exit
```

Comment: Have you checked that those paths are _not_ in your path before you update it?

Comment: Yup. Not there. That's why I prepended them.

Comment: Weird. I'm also blind; where's your export line? I don't see it in your .bashrc or .bash_profile. My .bash_profile just does a `PATH=` to prepend the ones I need.

Comment: The original .bashrc was `PATH=`. I changed it to `export PATH=` thinking it would solve the duplication problem. I'm going to add the full source for my `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Added source of `~/.bashrc` and changed back to original `PATH=` from `export PATH=`

Comment: I know for sure that `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin` was not in the original `$PATH` as calling `javac` resulted in `command not found`

Comment: It may be that your `~/.bashrc` is executing twice. Can you add `echo "foo"` at the end of `~/.bashrc` and see if `foo` prints once or twice?

Comment: Holy guacamole! `foo` does print out twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Cygwin installed, and I don't have a Windows machine, so I can't give you a boatload of details.

See if the `man bash` page can help you. In normal BASH, the `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, the `$HOME/.bash_profile`, the `$HOME/.bashrc`, and sometimes the `$HOME/.profile` are all read in depending whether this is a login shell or not. Cygwin has it's own special versions of each of these files in the `/etc` directory. However, there's also other scripts that get invoked and can affect your Cygwin environment. For example, there are special scripts to import Windows environment variables including `%PATH%`.

In Cygwin, the default is to include the Windows `%PATH%` variable as part of the Cygwin path. It's actually a general import of all Windows environment variables (and depending upon the installation, the `\` is sometimes converted to a `/` and short directory names are used).

If you open xterm windows and not standard Windows console windows for your Cygwin command line, you'll also have to check the *xserve* script (or whatever it's called) because that also imports a lot of stuff into the Cygwin environment.

I've used Cygwin in the past, and every time I use Cygwin, I find myself chasing down these exact things, plus a few other issues: For example, the default Kornshell load environment script has a bug in it. I believe they have a literal "^G" instead of a Ctrl-G, or maybe it was another control character. I can't remember. All I know is I spend about an hour or two *cleaning up* my Cygwin environment every time I install it. I like Cygwin, but it can be a pain.

Sorry I can't give you more specific directions.

Comment: Chased it down and solved it. Found out it was really caused by a customization I made to `C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat` to allow for a Windows context menu option to `Open current directory in Bash`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `PATH` to whatever you like (without a reference to `$PATH`). You shouldn't trust the `PATH` that some random sysadmin thinks is a good `PATH` anyway. Do this in the file sourced last for your shell.

Comment: Thanks Jens. I found that I needed to pass `--noprofile --norc` to `bash` when calling it via `--exec` from `mintty` in `C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat`. `bash` itself calls a command line via `-c` flag that allows me to `cd` to a passed in path before starting another inner `bash`. The inner `bash` gets to execute the `.bash_profile` and the `.bashrc`